# Debugging single page application angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I am working on an angular SPA application and I have encountered some problems. I need your help to debug the application to Because the debugging seems to me stuck

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which application are you using for debugging: Visual studio?, Visual studio code?, ... .